# Fill pandas column forward iteratively, but without using iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a pandas data frame with a column where a condition is met based on other elements in the data frame (not shown). Additionally,  I have a column that extends the validness one row further with the following rule:

**If a valid row is followed directly by ExtendsValid, that row is also valid, even if the underlying valid condition doesnt apply. Continue filling valid forward as long as ExtendsValid is 1**

I have illustrated the result in column "FinalValid" (desired result. Doesnt have to be a new column, can also fill Valid forward).
Note that rows 8 and 9 in the example also become valid.
Also note that row 13 does NOT result in FinalValid, because you need a preceding valid row. Preceding valid row can be Valid or an extended valid row.

So far if I had a problem like that I did a cumbersome multi-step process:

1. Create a  new column for when "Valid" or "ExtendsValid" is true
2. Create a new column marking the start point for each "sub-series" (a consecutive set of ones)
3. Number each sub-series
4. fillna using "group by" for each sub series

I can provide sample code but I am really looking for a totally different, more efficient approach, which of course must be non-iterating as well.

Any ideas would be welcome.

| # | Valid | ExtendsValid | FinalValid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 14 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? So far it seems you need `df["FinalValid"] = (df.Valid | df.ExtendsValid).astype(int)`

Comment: Edited example for more clarity (row 13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to ffill the 1s only if there is an uninterrupted series of 1s starting on Valid and eventually continuing on ExtendsValid.

For this you can use a [`groupby.cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html):

```
df['FinalValid'] = (
 (df['Valid']|df['ExtendsValid'])
 .groupby(df['Valid'].cumsum())
 .cummin()
 )
```

Output:

*NB. I slightly modified the input on row 3 to better illustrate the logic.*

```
     #  Valid  ExtendsValid  FinalValid
0    1      0             0           0
1    2      1             0           1
2    3      0             0           0
3    4      0             1           0
4    5      1             0           1
5    6      0             0           0
6    7      1             0           1
7    8      0             1           1
8    9      0             1           1
9   10      0             0           0
10  11      1             0           1
11  12      0             0           0
```

Comment: This appears to do exactly what I needed but I have to admit it uses some concepts I was not familiar with. Specifically what is this grouping by 2 columns in the "or" condition? How does it avoid marking FinalValid=1 in your row 3?

Comment: It's not grouping by two columns, `(df['Valid']|df['ExtendsValid'])` produces a Series, which is then grouped by another series `.groupby(df['Valid'].cumsum())`. `cummin` is responsible for discarding the 1s that are after any 0s within a group.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
state, data = 0, []
for v, e in zip(df.Valid, df.ExtendsValid):
    state = v or (not v and e and state)
    data.append(int(state))

df["FinalValid_new"] = data
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     #  Valid  ExtendsValid  FinalValid  FinalValid_new
0    1      0             0           0               0
1    2      1             0           1               1
2    3      0             0           0               0
3    4      0             0           0               0
4    5      1             0           1               1
5    6      0             0           0               0
6    7      1             0           1               1
7    8      0             1           1               1
8    9      0             1           1               1
9   10      0             0           0               0
10  11      1             0           1               1
11  12      0             0           0               0
12  13      0             1           0               0
13  14      0             0           0               0
```

---

Note: For more performance I recommend to look at [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) package.

---

EDIT: Example using [numba](/questions/tagged/numba):

```py
from numba import njit


@njit
def compute_valid(valid, extends_valid, out):
    state = 0
    for i, (v, e) in enumerate(zip(valid, extends_valid)):
        state = v or (not v and e and state)
        out[i] = int(state)


df["FinalValid_new"] = 0
compute_valid(
    df.Valid.to_numpy(), df.ExtendsValid.to_numpy(), df.FinalValid_new.to_numpy()
)
print(df)
```